# Issue with MS Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, azure-automation

I am trying to call Azure Automation job in *TENANT-A* from Flow in *TENANT-B*  using `Create Job` Flow. The connection account has Reader access to Azure Subscription and Contributor access to Resource Group which holds Automation account, it used to work fine few days ago, but now facing below error. Has anyone else faced this with MS-Flow.

```
The access token is from the wrong issuer'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/'. 
It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/' associated with this 
subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/' 
to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is 
no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate 
(up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, 
please try back later.
```